# What does per-O-acetylated glucopyranoside mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbohydrates

What does per-*O*-acetylated glucopyranoside mean?
Can you please break down the roots?

Comment: Per-_O_-acetylated sugars are sugars where _each_ (thus, _per_) hydroxyl group (thus _O_) is converted into an ester of HOAc. E.g., https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0103-50532015000400755 For glucose, for example, to get you glucose pentaacetate.

Answer (score 2):

Per-*O*-acetyl-glucopyranoside chemical structure is shown below. It is a fully acetylated glucose saccharide unit in the pyranose ring form.

It is mentioned in [Molbase](https://www.molbase.com/cas/66966-07-2.html) and
[Chemsrc](https://www.chemsrc.com/en/cas/66966-07-2_649026.html). Pubchem prefers calling it [B-L-Glucose pentaacetate](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/B-L-Glucose-pentaacetate) and Chemspider [1,2,3,4,6-penta-O-acetyl-B-L-glucopyranose](https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.7997502.html).

A search for CAS 66966-07-2 should return an assortment of suppliers and database details for the β configuration of acetylated carbohydrate.
[image: per-O-acetyl-glucopyranoside]

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are familiar with the concept of a glucopyranoside.

*Acetylated* means that at least one hydrogen atom has been replaced by an acetyl group $\ce{-C(=O)-CH3}$, typically abbreviated as $\ce{Ac}$. It is connected to the rest of the structure by the bond I have drawn at the front.

*O*-acetylation means that the substitution occurred on an oxygen atom. Thus, instead of an alcohol group (or a hemiacetal) we are dealing with an acetate (or an acetal ester) group: $\ce{-O-C(=O)-CH3}$ or $\ce{OAc}$.

*Per*-acetylation means that the substitution as described above has been performed on all possible atoms. This leads to the structure z1273 drew.